# How to create an adjustable Bézier curve?

Tags: graphics, splines

I tried to create an adjustable Bézier curve with the following simple code. However the curve didn't show up. What is the problem? Please help.

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {3, 3}};
bez = BezierFunction[pts ];

Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[lo], Green, Line[lo]}, Axes -> True], 
  ParametricPlot[bez[lo ], {t, 0, 1}], ImageSize -> { 200, 200 }],
 {{lo, pts}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image: Bézier curve Manipulate]

Comment: Works perfectly with me: "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps more compact:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[BezierFunction[lo]@t, {t, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Green, Line[lo]}], 
 {{lo, pts}, Locator}, 
 Initialization :> (pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {3, 3}})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: yes much better...was just being lazy but hopefully helpful

Answer (score 6):

I believe this should achieve your aim:

```
Manipulate[
 bez = BezierFunction[lo];
 Show[Graphics[{Red, Point[lo], Green, Line[lo]}, Axes -> True], 
  ParametricPlot[bez[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
  ImageSize -> {200, 200}], {{lo, pts}, Locator}, 
 Initialization :> (pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {3, 3}};)]
```

Quit kernel and try. Note: (i) the dynamic variable is the `lo`. `pts` are merely initial configuration (ii) the Bezier function $bez: [0,1]\mapsto R^2$-> `t` not `lo` as argument.

Comment: +1 for `hopefully helpful` :)